# Python: zipping a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

How can I zip an entire folder if I only know the name of the folder?
I've seen other similar questions, but when I try to use something like the code below it does zip the file, but when I open it I get zipname.zip.cpgz

```
import os
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile("zipname.zip", "w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk("foldername"):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
zf.close()
```

Comment: The code you've posted should work. By "when I open it" what do you mean... you are listing its table of contents and getting strange filenames? Are you sure they are different than the files on your machine? It seems like your file system already has some gzipped files in it and you are just sticking them in your archive.

Comment: @tdelaney The trouble is it creates a cpgz file, and when I try to open it it creates a zip file, and that goes in circles. This can happen when there's a corrupted file or something, so I'm wondering if the code is wrong.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried unzipping it from the command line, but it says it's empty.

Comment: You shouldn't need the 'zf.write(dirname)' line.  The folder will automatically be written when you write the full path.

Comment: @RobDavis Removing it does not work either :(

Comment: By chance are you running this in a virtual environment and copying the zip file across the barrier?  Could you add `zf.testzip()` to the end of your code and see if it throws an error?

Comment: Are you zipping into a file in the same directory?

Comment: Putting the .zip into the same directory you are zipping has the unfortunate effect of adding some of the zipped content into the archive again, but its mostly harmless in the default `zipfile`. There are other, faster, zipfile implementations out there. Have you installed one of those? What does `zipfile.__file__` say? Does `help(zipfile)` give any hints that its not standard?

Comment: @RobDavis - `zf.write(dirname)` is needed if you want to include empty directories in the zip file.

Comment: @tdelaney truth... Didn't think about that one.